# Detect Google Cloud Project Id from a container in Google hosted Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-bigtable

Detect Google Cloud Project Id from a container in Google hosted Kubernetes cluster.

When connecting to BigTable; I need to provide the Google Project Id. Is there a way to detect this automatically from within K8s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has some libraries for this too: `ServiceOptions.getDefaultProjectId`

https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/index.html

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-core/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/ServiceOptions.java

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-core

Answer (score 5):

In Python, you can find the project id this way:

```
import google.auth
_, PROJECT_ID = google.auth.default()
```

The original question didn't mention what programming language was being used, and I had the same question for Python.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the metadata service. Example:

```
curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" -w '\n' http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/numeric-project-id
```

This will work from any VM running on Google Compute Engine or Container Engine.

See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata:

> Google Compute Engine defines a set of default metadata entries that provide information about your instance or project. Default metadata is always defined and set by the server.
>
> ...
>
> `numeric-project-id`  The numeric project ID of the instance, which is not the same as the project name visible in the Google Cloud Platform Console. This value is different from the project-id metadata entry value.
>
> `project-id`  The project ID.